# extra value is appending to binding in orm query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an orm query in my project . I send fixed number of parameters to the query but when I view the Query Log, an extra parameter is appended to the binding.

```
array:1 [
 0 => array:3 [
"query" => "SELECT * FROM business_schedules WHERE(archive = ? 
   AND (day = ? AND date IS NULL) OR (day = ? AND date = ?) 
     AND city = ?) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM business WHERE
      business_schedules.business_id = business.id AND
      category_id IN(?))"
"bindings" => array:7 [
  0 => 0
  1 => "Wednesday"
  2 => "Wednesday"
  3 => "2017-09-19"
  4 => "Lahore"
  5 => 50
  6 => "1"
   ]
"time" => 1.11
 ]
]
```

Note that I have place for only 6 parameters in my query but an extra value **50** is appending all the time. 
What could be the reasons behind this ?